# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\codeinventor\login.php on line 18

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();
 
    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');
 
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];

// Select the database to use

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$email and password=$password";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($row["email"]==$email && $row["password"]==$pass)
    echo"You are successful login.";
else
    echo"Sorry, your email or password is not valid, Please try again.";
?>
```

I tried to code the line of error return after $result but the same error display after login.

this error shows up

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
> boolean given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\codeinventor\login.php on line 18
>
> Sorry, your email or password is not valid, Please try again.

Comment: print the query and run it phpmyadmin and see whats happening

Comment: try enclose $email and $password in single quote '$email'

Comment: @Jitendra it's work but it display Connected SuccessfullySorry, your email or password is not valid, Please try again. I want it to redirect to another page. How to do it? and want to figure it out if the user login.

Comment: may be you use 'Connected Successfully' in connection.php for successfull connection. change it to not successfull then show message

Comment: Sorry forget to tell you it's work. Right now, I'm trying to code Welcome (username)! but that didn't work. Trying to work it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_query` returns false because something is wrong with your query. You can retrieve the error message from the MySQL server with `mysqli_error($connection)` for debugging.

Most likely, the problem is that `$email` and `$password` are strings, but you have neither quoted nor escaped them in your query. In addition, you have used the variable `$password` in the query, but actually named it `$pass`.
The way you're building your query is especially dangerous since it is prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). A better approach would be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email) . "' and password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass) . "'";
```

Furthermore, I do not recommend checking the existence of the row for logins due to the danger of SQL injection. Fetching the password of the user from the database and comparing it to the given password in the PHP code could be safer. For example, with your unescaped (but properly quoted) query an attacker could specify `"' OR TRUE"` or something similar as password so that the query wouldn't actually check if the password is correct.

---

**Edit:** As Jordy suggested in the comments, [prepared statements](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) would not only be safe, but also more elegant than escaping the parameters manually:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, 'SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $real_pass);

if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt) && $real_pass == $pass)
    echo "Login successful";
else
    echo "Sorry, your email or password is not valid, Please try again.";

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: An even better approach would be using parameterized queries.

Comment: This would cause mysqli error and may generate PHP `warning` stating that `mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given`

Comment: @Jordy: You're absolutely right. I have added a note on that.

Comment: @SagarGuhe: Thanks! I've corrected that. I usually rather work with the object-oriented interface of mysqli ;)

Comment: In index input name= "email" and "password". In database, email and password. In my register.php, i type  $username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($password);

Comment: I don't know I'm new to sql and a little bit of php.

Comment: In your own code, you have declared: `$pass = $_POST["password"];` But later on, you've referred to it as `$password`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching the row why dont you just count the number of rows. It would be better so the code will be.

```
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row_cnt > 0)
    echo"You are successful login.";
else
    echo"Sorry, your email or password is not valid, Please try again.";
```